# Wicket: Avoid Assigning ListChoice's Model to a Form's Model

Tags: java, apache, wicket

Been playing around with this for a couple of hours and can't seem to get my head around it.

In Wicket, a List Choice takes a list of models that will represent the choices that make up the list. When the Form that the List Choice is added to is submitted, Wicket binds the selected choice's model to the Form's model.

But what if I don't want the entire model bound and instead a specific property?

For example:

```
public class FormModel {
        private int locationId;

        public void setLocationId(int id) {
            this.locationId = id;
        }
    }

    public class LocationModel {
        private int id;

        public int getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
    }

    <select wicket:id="LocationId" id="LocationId" name="LocationId" size="1">
        <option value="#">#</option>
    </select>
```

When the form is submitted, Wicket will attempt to bind an entire LocationModel to the FormModel, where clearly I just want to bind it's **locationId** property.

I am already using a ChoiceRenderer but that seems to only work when the form is rendered not when it is submitted.

The result is an ultimate class cast exception since Wicket won't be able to convert a LocationModel to an integer.

I would hate to create another model specifically for the form to accept a LocationModel.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Model object of a `DropDownChoice` (chosen value) is always one of the objects in the choices List. So, it's not possible to provide a List of choices in which elements are of one type, and store the selection in the `DropDownChoice`'s `Model` in an object of a different type (*).

Just provide a `List<Integer>`. In case you're ok with that `locationId` as `<option>`'s text, an `IChoiceRenderer` wouldn't be necessary. Otherwise, your `IChoiceRenderer` should come up with the description with the `locationId`, for instance with a call to a helper function `getDescriptionForLocationId(Integer locationId)`.

If the implementation of that `getDescriptionForLocationId` function would be expensive, there's another approach you can use:

1. Implement a custom `IModel` that receives a `Map<Integer, String>` (or builds it up during `getObject()` ), and in its `getObject()`, return the keys from the `Map`. That will provide a List as the DropDownChoice's choices.
2. Implement a `getDescription()` method in your custom `IModel` class that will query the `Map` for the description of an `Integer`.
3. In the `IChoiceRenderer`, get the `DropDownChoice`'s Model and call its `getDescription()` to get the proper description.

Here's a little sample: http://pastebin.com/DhKbsdQz

Please notice the drawbacks of this approach: The `Map` will get serialized along with the `Model` (it could also be extending [`LoadableDetachableModel`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/model/LoadableDetachableModel.html) for efficiency)

(*) Thinking about it, Wicket uses `equals()` behind the scenes in order to establish the correspondence between the ddc's ModelObject and the elements in the List of choices, so it has its logic things are this way.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly; Are you saying give the list choice a list of integers and inside my IChoiceRenderer, pull the relevant location represented by each ID when it is displayed?

Comment: Indeed. See my edit for an alternative if pulling descriptions is expensive.

Comment: Your example worked great. Thanks for the great detailed answer.